# How to return multiple custom filters in a function based view

Tags: python, django

So I have written three custom filters, from which I need two in my view to display them on my webpage.

This is my filters.py

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title']


class TagFilter(django_filters.CharFilter):
    field_class = TagField

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('lookup_expr', 'in')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class MyTagFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    tags = TagFilter(field_name='tags__name')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['tags']
```

and my view looks this at the moment:

```
def product_list(request):
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    product_filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)
    tag_filter = MyTagFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)
    return render(request, 'cart/product-list.html', {'filter': product_filter})
```

I tried to make a dictionary out of the two filters and return them in the render method, but this didn't work and they don't show up in my template, which looks like this

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <form method="get">
                {{ filter.form|crispy }}
                <button class="btn btn-sm amphibian-button-primary btn-block element-shadow img-audio">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Can anybody guide me into the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you load the crispy tag on top of your template? `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}`
And what is the output you get when you print your `product_filter`?

Comment: yes, crispy_form_tags is loaded in my template. I have only posted the part where I am using the filters. I was able to load on of my filters into my templates, either the product or the tag_filter, but as soon as I try to load both of them, nothing appears on my page.